# Translate Objective-C code into Swift

Tags: swift

I'm new in Swift and I would like if someone could tell me how can I translate the following code fragment written in **Objective-C** *to* **Swift**.

**Code:**

```objc
id< JavaUtilConcurrentConcurrentNavigableMap > mapVu = mmcache->kvmap_;
```

**The corresponding header:**

```objc
@interface MemCache : NSObject { 
          JavaUtilConcurrentConcurrentLinkedDeque *kvqueue_; 
}
```

Comment: That's some very weird Objective-C; it looks *very* old. Where did it come from? Are you permitted to change it?

Comment: i can't change it because there is so much classes if i change one i have to change all the classes where the changed one is used

Comment: all that'd be normal would be a getter for `kvmap` — something Swift could call to get the map rather than the current approach of directly reading the instance variable. You could keep the instance variable for all your existing code. It's very, very weird by modern standards that an instance variable is exposed like this but you don't need to stop doing that just to provide a getter.

Comment: but the kvmap_ is a  reference to a protocol ; is it possible to write a get function that can return it ?

Comment: It's a reference to a class that represents itself as implementing a protocol. The getter would look like `- (id <JavaUtilConcurrentConcurrentNavigableMap>)kvmap;` or e.g. `@property (nonatomic, readonly) id <JavaUtilConcurrentConcurrentNavigableMap> kvmap;` if you wanted to use property syntax. You can also pass around references to protocols if you want — they exist in the runtime just like metaclasses do — but it's rarely done.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of confusion later: **You cannot access the instance variables of an Objective-C class from within Swift in a regular / proper manner.** Take a look at the [answer by Leo Natan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30980709/2442804) for how to work around that.

*The previous answer below basically focused on the protocol rather than the instance variables*

In swift you can just have the protocol as the type:

```swift
let mapVu:JavaUtilConcurrentConcurrentNavigableMap = mmcache.kvmap_
```

See a working example:

```swift
protocol JavautilBlaBla {
}

class Class1: JavautilBlaBla {
    override init() {
    }
}

class Class2 {
    var kvmap_:Class1

    override init() {
        kvmap_ = Class1()
    }
}

let mmcache = Class2()

let mapVu:JavautilBlaBla = mmcache.kvmap_
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , but it's not done with me .. when i have e write your solution i get an error which is : mmcache doesn't contain a kvmap_ variable, therefore when i verify the header file relative to the type of the object mmcache  i have find kvmap_ present. I don't know why that not done with me

Comment: the header file is on objective c , i'm using both language objective c and swift in the same application and i import the header file using a bridging header file.  these is the content of the header :, please see the question i update them

Comment: @Sam i doubt you can do that in objective-C either because the variable is protected.

Comment: i have write it in objective c and that work well, whereas now i need it on swift... even kvmap_ is public too , it's not private

Comment: @Sam is your code written in a subclass of `OrgKalimaCacheServerMemCache`?

Comment: the actual classe where i try to to obtain the kvmap_ is not a subclass OrgKalimaCacheServerMemCache, it's another but before i use it i have instantiate the class ( the object) and that's done ! the content of the implementation code of the class OrgKalimaCacheServerMemCache is in a static library that i linked to the project.

Comment: @Sam okay... after a bit of searching around i have to say: not possible. you can not access the instance variables of an objective-c class from swift. :(

Comment: :( thank you , i have to search another way to get the kvmap_ so.. thanks so much

Comment: @Sam was new to me too, the normal workarounds seem to be to create a getter for the variable or to make the instance variable a property.

Comment: @Sam See my answer for a method to access the instance variable.

Answer (score 2):

The only current way to access an instance variable is to use `valueForKey()`.

So,

```
let mapVu = mmcache.valueForKey("kvmap_") as! JavaUtilConcurrentConcurrentNavigableMap!
```

Comment: yes that's work, but before you publish this solution i have write  a get function and that work too ... your solution i try it in another case and i find that it's working too ...thank you